# What kind of shrub or bush is this, black berries, elongated leaves?

Tags: identification, shrubs

There are a couple of these bushes next to my house. I tried to identify them, but can't find them. Leaves are elongated, alternating and unlobed. They are ever so slightly serrated. You can see that a little in the second picture. The berries are almost black when ripe, or red when not. The shrub is located in Germany.

[image: Shrub with berries]
[image: Closeup of leaves]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shrub is definitely a Prunus and I'm trying to decide whether its Prunus lusitanica or P. laurocerasus - the leaves seem a little too narrow for the latter, unless this is a small variety such as 'Otto Luyken', which I can't tell from the photo. The berries do dangle in this way, and they are red to start with, turning black when ripe. The leaves on this plant are toxic, but the berries not so much, though they are not at all pleasant to eat.